# Excel - How to display row numbers on the right side

Tags: microsoft-excel

The title sums it up, I would like row numbers to show up either only on the right side, or ideally on both left and right sides. I'm using Excel 2016. I cannot find anything either on this site or elsewhere on the Internet to do that. Thank you !

Comment: I don't think it's possible in Excel.  You may find add-in which does it for you,  but software recommendation is off-topic  here.

Comment: You can show Row numbers on Right side but also the column will start from the Right also look in the options

Comment: Page Layout Sheet Right to Left

Comment: Could you share some sample data or image with us, will  help us to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

In Excel Options:

[image]

Just check the right-to-left checkbox.

Comment: On my version, that will also reverse the column headers.